# Если делать запросы с помощью объектов - это повысит защиту от SQL инъекций?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

Сначала приведу пример из документации `typeorm`:

> Вместо того, чтобы писать так (в `QueryBuilder`):

```
where("user.name = '" + name + "')
```

> Нужно писать так:

```
where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
```

Вопрос: если делать запрос не через `QueryBuilder`, а через репозиторий:

```
await this.userRepository.find({
   where: {
     name: name,
   },
});
```

То есть передавать объект, то это даст такой же уровень защиты от SQLI или нет?

Comment: параметры запроса будут одинаково очищены священным огнём

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо